# How to write cypher statement to combine nodes when an OPTIONAL MATCH is null?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, match, option-type

## Background

Hi all, I am currently trying to write a cypher statement that allows me to find a set of paths on a map from a starting point. **I want my search result to *always* return connecting streets within 5 nodes. Optionally, if there's a nearby hospital, I would like my search pattern to also indicate nearby hospitals.**

## Main Problem

Because there isn't always a nearby hospital to the current street, **sometimes my optional match search pattern comes back as null**. Here's the current cypher statement I'm using:

```
MATCH path=(a:Street {id: 123})-[:CONNECTED_TO*..5]-(b:Street)
OPTIONAL MATCH optionalPath=(b)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(hospital:Hospital)
WHERE ALL (x IN nodes(path) WHERE (x:Street))
WITH DISTINCT nodes(path) + nodes(optionalPath) as n
UNWIND n as nodes
RETURN DISTINCT nodes;
```

However, **this syntax only works if** `optionalPath` **contains nodes**. If it doesn't, the statement `nodes(path) + nodes(optionalPath)` is an operation adding null and I get no records. This is true even the `nodes(path)` term does contain nodes.

What's the best way to get around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE` to replace a `NULL` with some other value. For example:

```
MATCH path=(:Street {id: 123})-[:CONNECTED_TO*..5]-(b:Street)
WHERE ALL (x IN nodes(path) WHERE x:Street)
OPTIONAL MATCH optionalPath=(b)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(hospital:Hospital)
WITH nodes(path) + COALESCE(nodes(optionalPath), []) as n
UNWIND n as nodes
RETURN DISTINCT nodes;
```

I have also made a few other improvements:

1. The `WHERE` clause was moved up right after the first `MATCH`. This eliminates the unwanted `path` values immediately. Your original query would get all `path` values (even unwanted ones) and always the perform the second `MATCH` query, and only eliminate unwanted paths afterwards. (But, it is actually not clear if you even need the `WHERE` clause at all; for example, if the `CONNECTED_TO` relationship is only used between `Street` nodes.)
2. The `DISTINCT` in your `WITH` clause would have prevented duplicate `n` collections, but the collections internally could have had duplicate paths. This was probably not what you wanted.

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for exactly and your improvements are great. Re: (1) This makes sense and will improve query search time; also my dataset is really rich (just simplified it here for posting the question) and I've found that unless I specify that all nodes in the path have to be of type Street, I will get paths that traverse other types of nodes; (2) thanks for pointing this out. I'm still learning cypher so some of these mistakes don't stand out to me immediately.

Comment: Quick followup. I did some testing, and if I use COALESCE(path, []) when the path is not null, I'm get a type error: "Type mismatch: expected Node but was Any, Map, Node". I thought COALESCE took the first non-null entry and continued along the query.

Comment: First of all, `COALESCE(path, [])` makes no sense, since a path is not a collection; you need to make sure the 2 arguments are of the same type, or else the rest of your Cypher will not always get the expected type. Also, the error is probably coming from the clause that is trying to make use of the result of the `COALESCE`. This sounds like a new question, if you continue to have issues.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't really want the path, just all the street nodes within 5 steps, plus any connected hospitals. So I would simplify your query to just that, and then condense the 3 columns down to 1.

```
MATCH (a:Street {id: 123})-[:CONNECTED_TO*..5]-(b:Street)
OPTIONAL MATCH (b)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(hospital:Hospital)
WITH collect(a) + collect(b) + collect(hospital) as n
UNWIND n as nodez
RETURN DISTINCT nodez;
```

If Streets can be indirectly connected (hospital in between), Than I'd adjust like this

```
MATCH (a:Street {id: 123})-[:CONNECTED_TO]-(b:Street)
WITH a as nodez, b as a
MATCH (a)-[:CONNECTED_TO]-(b:Street)
WITH nodez+collect(b) as nodez, b as a
MATCH (a)-[:CONNECTED_TO]-(b:Street)
WITH nodez+collect(b) as nodez, b as a
MATCH (a)-[:CONNECTED_TO]-(b:Street)
WITH nodez+collect(b) as nodez, b as a
MATCH (a)-[:CONNECTED_TO]-(b:Street)
WITH nodez+collect(b) as nodez, b as a
OPTIONAL MATCH (b)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(hospital:Hospital)
WITH nodez + collect(hospital) as n
UNWIND n as nodez
RETURN DISTINCT nodez;
```

It's a bit more verbose, but just says exactly what you  want (and also adds the start node to the hospital check list)